# Frequency of a value in a list of entities

Tags: java, list, entity, frequency

I have an entity named Elementfisa, which contains as values (id,Post,Sarcina). Now, Post(Int Id,String Nume,String Tip) and Sarcina(Int Id,String Desc) are also entities. I have a List of all the elements I added as Elementfisa, and I want to get in a separate list the frequency of every Sarcina that every Elementfisa contains. This is my code right now:

```
    int nr=0;
    List<Integer> frecv=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Sarcina> sarcini = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Elementfisa> efuri=findEFAll();
    for (Elementfisa i : efuri)
    {
        nr=0;
        for (Sarcina s : sarcini)
            if (s.equals(i.getSarcina()))
                    nr=1;
        if (nr==0)
        {
            int freq = Collections.frequency(efuri, i.getSarcina());
            sarcini.add(i.getSarcina());
            frecv.add(freq);
        }
    }
```

(findEFAll() returns every element contained in a Hashmap from a repository)
But for some reason, while the sarcini list contains all the Sarcina from every Elementfisa, the frequency list will show 0 on every position. What should I change so every position should show the correct number of occurrences?

Comment: Is efuri empty?

Comment: No, it contains Elementfisa entities (id,Post,Sarcina)

Comment: You could replace `if(nr == 0)` with `if(!sarcini.contains(i.getSarcina()))` and eliminate the `nr` code. Also, have you overridden `equals()`?

Comment: No, I haven't touched equal at all, so it should use the default Java implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `Collections.frequency()` on `efuri`, a `List<Elementfisa>`. But you're passing `i.getSarcina()` to it, a `Sarcina` object. A `List` of `Elementfisa` cannot possibly contain a `Sarcina` object, so you get zero. You may have passed the wrong list  to the method.

---

Edit:
To look at all `Sarcina`s in `efuri`, you can do this using Java 8 streams:

```
efuri.stream().map(element -> element.getSarcina())
    .collect(Collectors.toList()).contains(i.getSarcina())
```

Breakdown:

```
efuri.stream() //Turns this into a stream of Elementfisa
.map(element -> element.getSarcina()) //Turns this into a stream of Sarcina
.collect(Collectors.toList()) //Turn this into a list
.contains(i.getSarcina()) //Check if the list contains the Sarcina
```

Comment: I thought that was the problem, but how can I extract from "efuri" the Sarcina, so I can compare it with i.getSarcina()? Or is there another method  to compare the current i.getSarcina() with every Sarcina value from "efuri", so I can get the frequency?

Comment: @Artyomska Edited answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. The solution worked and now I get the correct frequency :)

Comment: @Artyomska no problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you do not need to override `equals()` of `Elementisa`? (and `hashcode()` too).  The default Java `equals()` does not seem to get what you want because it would be checking the identity (not the value) of two `Elementisa` objects, while in your logic, two such objects with the same values may be considered as equivalent.

For more information on `equals()`, see

[What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java/27609#27609)

Comment: The list itself contains `Elementisa`s but they are checking if the list contains `Sarcina`s, equals wouldn't help much here